# Facebook user url by id

Tags: facebook

I have a list of FB ids, is there a canon way of constructing their FB url without a graph query?

For example, I have ids 3, 4, 5, and i want the Facebook URL for them without using the graph api and save them down

Comment: "without using the graph api" - you need to perform requests to facebook anyway. Why not to do it correctly (using graph api)?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:** This information is no more given by facebook. There is an official announcement for the behavior change (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/) but none for its alternative.

Yes, Just use this link and append your ID to the `id` parameter:

```
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<UID>
```

So for example:

```
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=4
```

Will redirect you automatically to `https://www.facebook.com/zuck` Which is Mark Zuckerberg's profile.

If you want to do this for all your ids, then you can do it using a loop.

If you'd like, I can provide you with a snippet.

**UPDATE:** Alternatively, You can also do this:

```
https://facebook.com/<UID>
```

So that would be: https://facebook.com/4 which would automatically redirect to Zuck!

Comment: And how to retrieve the result (redirect) url automatically?

Comment: If the only purpose of the url is to simply redirect your user to their profile or any other profile, you can use the above url and fb will automatically send the person to the appropriate profile. But if the purpose is to fetch their data, then you'll have to use graph API.

Comment: I'm not an OP, and OP asked how to retrieve urls ;-)

Comment: Yeah, But he wants the url without using graph API, So that's the easiest way to do this :D

Comment: what's the way? You only provided the user-oriented way. How to obtain an url programmatically?

Comment: There is no point in obtaining an url programmatically, If you want to obtain programmatically, then it's just better to use graph API, this is good just to build a list or to use with <a> Tag. Like say you want to link user's image to their profile. You can use the above url if you or the OP doesn't want to make a call to fb just for a link.

Comment: This solution seems to not be working anymore. I've made a [convenient page](http://facebook.montezuma.it/facebook_get_user_by_id.html) that gives you the facebook profile page from its ID. Hope it can save some time.

Comment: @LucaFagioli: Not sure why it isn't working for you. It's perfectly working fine as of now. Tested just now.

Comment: @SyedI.R It has not been working for some weeks. I am sure about that because I have tested recently. I thought it was deprecated for good, but now I can see that they had made it working again.

Comment: @LucaFagioli: I see, Ok. I added another method too.

Comment: Update: Links changed to https

Comment: It doesn't work now. Is facebook.com/<UID> disabled ?

Comment: It looks like it is disabled. Not working for me too.

Comment: Also, this url is not working now :/ https://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/picture?type=large

Comment: You can get a valid Link by:
[Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)   
-> with Query "me?fields=id,name,link"     
-> Answer ist like @davidhq says "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152384781676191"     
-> BUT, it is not working yet     
=> But if the Facebook API do not gives an valid Link, it is Problem on Facebook - Site.

Comment: `https://facebook.com/<UID>` using this and it keeps redirecting me to my home page

Comment: also this id is redirecting to 4e24bd21cb3de37c1d17a3743d3a4716 Mark Zuckerberg's profile. How a user can have two ids at the same time?

Comment: Facebook changed this url.

Answer (score 75):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, this does:

```
https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152384781676191
```

Comment: I had troubles with the ?id url on some ids too, this does the trick. Thanks David.

Comment: Same here, this one is perfect. Thanks David.

Comment: not working anymore. at least not working for me. "This page isn't available"

Comment: https://onezero.medium.com/why-decentralization-matters-5e3f79f7638e

Answer (score 23):

The easiest and the most correct (and legal) way is to use graph api.

Just perform the request: http://graph.facebook.com/4

which returns

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

and take the `link` key.

You can also reduce the traffic by using `fields` parameter: http://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=link to get only what you need:

```
{
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "id": "4"
}
```

Comment: I think it does not work without `access_token` and `https`. Example: `https://graph.facebook.com/4?access_token=YOUR_YOKEN`

Comment: Did not work, IE11, but the first URLs do retrieve the same profile without nickname, from ID

Comment: this is not deprecated.

Comment: does not work as of Feb. 22, 2018. no link/username found :(

Comment: @Theo 5.5 years passed ‍♂️ time flies

Comment: yeah. you have some new leads mate?

Comment: sorry it works, i just had to add the `fields=link` on url query
`https://graph.facebook.com/<ID>?fields=link&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Comment: The link field does not return the link to the user, but instead:
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/ID/",

Comment: as of June 23 this no longer works with or without the fields=link

Comment: its not working anymore and there is absolute no alternatives anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer seems outdated and it won't work.

Facebook now only gives unique ID related to app which isn't equal to userId and profileUrl and username will come out to be empty.

Doing `me?fields=id,name,links` is also depreciated after Graph Version 2.4

The only option now is to request for user_links permission from your developer console.

[image]

and the pass it in scope when doing facebook login

```
scope: ['user_link'] }
```

or by doing an api call

Answer (score 1):

**As of now (NOV-2019)**, graph.api V5.0

graph API says, [refer graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/)

> A link to the person's Timeline. The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.

[image: doc]

Answer (score 0):

I've collected info together:

- add into scope `user_link`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/
- add into fields request `link` (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=link,name,email)
- get `link` from answer. Be aware of field length- in my case it is 202: https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZADpBWEd0SlhFZAElYa3BQT3U3Tm4xWVRLSlJfYUdUM3Y4YmIwQjBaRkM0VDBMNURQdUhhYk5NRDJoR1ZA5ZA1JOdGNwampsSTQyMDQwbW93bkp0dnZAmOXg3NTFISFVZAQlRscWQ5eEZAvcU4xZAC1B/

And finaly: it doen't work without additional Facebook permission check:(