# Can't find the user facebook url on the user table

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i need to get the user's facebook url (the one of his own facebook page), eg:

> https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx.

i don't know if this is always given by facebook, for me it's the same as the part of my email address lying on the left of the "@"

> xxxxxxxx@gmail.com

(i don't know if this can be as UUI..).

i don't need to show any code, how to meet quality standards if i just need to ask this simple question ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/ -> _profile_url – string – The URL to a user's profile_ … not much of reader, hm?

Comment: thanks, i've a headacke.. :)

Answer (score 0):

the user fb url can be gotten by using this url : http://facebook.com/profile.php?id= see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827922/1705922