# Find Facebook profile URL by ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an old project, which is collecting and writing to SQL database registered users Facebook IDs. Then I created dynamic link to the user profile: https://facebook.com/{user-ID}. Now this URL doesn't work. How can I build a dynamic link to registered user profile by userID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52577611/10283047

Comment: You can not build it yourself any more, you need to request it via API. The user has to give permission first, and it will only work for friends of the user.

Comment: It's not possible now with grph api V5.0 refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58860774/7039250